# Proper approach to sharing CMake module across projects?

Tags: module, cmake

I have written a CMake module that contains a couple of useful macros that I would like to use across a number of other CMake projects. However, I'm not sure where to put the module.

I would like to be able to do this inside each project that uses the macro:

```
include(MyModule)
```

However, I'm not sure if there is an easy and cross-platform way of achieving this. In fact, I can't even get it to work on Unix. I put the module (`MyModule.cmake`) in the following locations:

- `/usr/lib/cmake/`
- `/usr/lib/cmake/Modules`
- `/usr/local/lib/cmake`
- `/usr/local/lib/cmake/Modules`

...and the project with the `include()` was unable to load the module.

What is the correct location for this module? Is there a better approach?

I should also point out that the macros are *not* related to "finding" a third-party library and therefore have nothing to do with `find_package()`.

Answer (score 0):

Put the module in a directory of your choice, and then add that directory to [`CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.html) using `list(APPEND)`.

You can even host that module somewhere and then download it via [`file(DOWNLOAD)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#download). If you download it to the same directory as the current CMake script being processed, you just `include(MyModule.cmake)` and don't need to modify `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`.

You could download the file to a common location on disk and then add a check using `if(EXISTS "${module_location_on_disk}")` to skip the download if it's already downloaded. Of course, more logic will be required if your module changes, or you want to have a common location and multiple versions of the module, but that's out of those scope of your question.